# XPATH select on XML tags with attributes causes error

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML: (Reduced the repeated rows to reduce size)

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

I need to select the catalog tag on my xsl file with: <xsl:copy-of select="catalog"/>
It works if I remove all attributes like this `"<catalog>"`

How to select the catalog tag when there's attributes on it?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Namespace declarations are not attributes.

Comment: My lack of XML knowledge  blocked me from finding the real "question", indeed I meant namespaces not "attributes" , thanks for linking to the related questions, Solved my issue.